# How can I speed up this MATLAB code with a whileloop?

Tags: matlab, while-loop, parallel-processing, gpu, combinations

I'm using a code that calculates expectation value of probabilities. This code contains a while-loop that finds all possible combinations and adds up products of probability combinations. However, when the number of elements becomes large(over 40) it takes too much time, and I want to make the code faster. 
The code is as follow-

```
function pcs = combsum(N,K,prbv)
nprbv=1-prbv;                   %prbv: probability vector
WV = 1:K;                       % Working vector.
lim = K;                        % Sets the limit for working index.
inc = 0;                        % Controls which element of WV is being worked on.
pcs = 0;
stopp=0;
while stopp==0  
    if logical((inc+lim)-N) 
        stp = inc;              % This is where the for loop below stops.
        flg = 0;                % Used for resetting inc.
    else
        stp = 1;
        flg = 1;
    end
      for jj = 1:stp
          WV(K  + jj - inc) = lim + jj;    % Faster than a vector assignment.
      end
      PV=nprbv;
      PV(WV)=prbv(WV);
      pcs=prod(PV)+pcs;
      inc = inc*flg + 1;         % Increment the counter.
      lim = WV(K - inc + 1 );    % lim for next run.
      if (inc==K)&&(lim==N-K)
          stopp=1;
          WV = (N-K+1):N;
          PV=nprbv;
          PV(WV)=prbv(WV);
          pcs=prod(PV)+pcs;
      end
  end
```

Is there a way to reduce calculation time? I wonder if parallel computing using GPU would help.

I tried to remove dependent variables in a loop for parallel computing, and I made a matrix of possible combinations using 'combnk' function. This worked faster.

```
nprbv=1-prbv;   %prbv : a probability vector 
N = 40;
K = 4;

n_combnk = size(combnk(1:N,K),1);

PV_mat = repmat(nprbv,n_combnk,1);

cnt = 0;
tic;
for i = 1:N-K+1
    for j = i+1:N-K+2
        for k = j+1:N-K+3
            for l = k+1:N-K+4
                cnt = cnt+1;
                PV_mat(cnt,i) = prbv(i);
                PV_mat(cnt,j) = prbv(j);
                PV_mat(cnt,k) = prbv(k);
                PV_mat(cnt,l) = prbv(l);
            end
        end
    end
end
toc;
tic;
pcs_rr = sum(prod(PV_mat,2));  
toc;
```

However, when K value gets larger, an out-of-memory problem happens in building a combination matrix(PV_mat). How can I break up the big matrix into small ones to avoid memory problem?

Comment: Could you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: Input N=3, K=2, prbv=[p1, p2, p3]         Output p1*p2*(1-p3)+p1*(1-p2)*p3+p1*(1-p2)*(1-p3)

Comment: Parallel computing can only help if you can divide up the calculation into independent chunks that can each be executed without depending on the others. It doesn't look as if this is the case here. Rather than ask us to figure out what your code is doing, can you explain what the calculation or algorithm is supposed to be - perhaps there's an alternative way of doing it that can be vectorised? Have you run the profiler on this code to find out which steps are slowest?

Comment: Too much code. Please be more specific. Otherwise, Google vectorization and learn what you can find there first.